# facebook send button returned status code 200

Tags: facebook, http, send, facebook-social-plugins

I'm using the facebook social plugin with an embedded ruby url which references: http://www.facebook.com/pages/my_page/my_page_id Specifically, the like button functionality works, but the send button functionality results in an error.

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href='<%= @fb_url %>' data-send="true"  data-colorscheme="dark" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```

> The page at http://www.facebook.com/pages/my_page/my_page_id could
>   not be reached because the server returned status code 200.

[image]

[image]

Have you ever seen this? This doesn't even make sense: a status code 200 is - OK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved the problem:

This is related to URLs that redirect. The like button supports them, the share button does not.

Comment: The solution in my case was to use the facebook page_id, which I store in my db to deploy apps. In my rails controller I used the gem Koala, a facebook api wrapper, to query facebook for the exact page url. I sent this to my rendered send/like buttons and this solved the issue in my case. ... you are into axis and allies ey? I love that game. Is this project you are working on open source? I might be down for a collaboration. - Jz