# The page at "url" could not be reached because the server returned status code 200

Tags: facebook-like, send

I deployed a like button on my third party site. The like button works but the send button does not, it gives me the following error:

The page at "url" could not be reached because the server returned status code 200.

Any ideas?

Comment: this looks like a duplication of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567633/facebook-send-button-returned-status-code-200

Comment: I have the exact page url and plugged it in but it still doesn't work. This is for a business page and I have claimed the url so it's a redirect but once I put the actual url it still gives me a problem.

Comment: You're not writing enough information that can help understand why exactly you get this message.  The best I can do to help is to tell you about the facebook debug tool: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug which helps you see what happens when facebook "crawls" the url.

Comment: The other article you referenced referred to Urls that redirect. I figured that was pertaining to the the url that I claimed as a business page www.facebook.com/StagecoachWineTours If you go to my website I have deployed the send button again so you may see the error when you click it. The page id is 97122673369 The debugger doesn't show a problem

Comment: I did find a work around. If I publish the like button with the send button "false" and create a separate send button it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

I did my homework and are facing the same message
and NOT with a Facebook page or a redirected page. A plain HTML page.
original with the error
http://www.ffkama.be/html/2_ekf_wkf_2012_euro_senior_1.asp
As ALL other pages work and the FB code is a server include, so the same for all pages, I saved the page under a new name and it solved the problem
http://www.ffkama.be/html/2_ekf_wkf_2012_euro_senior_0.asp

What happened to me. I made the page, included the meta property="og:title" stuff, saved the page and got the error. I FORGOT the  prefix="og:  in the head tag.

After that, whatever I did, no og code, good og code, nothing works until I saved under a different name.

So all I can see is that the page got cached somewhere and after that, whatever you do, the cached page will throw the error in.

Hope this helps
Chris